# Check for consecutive repeats in an array

Tags: java, arrays

so say i have this array

```
private Class[][] timetable = new Class[Main.days][Main.hours];
```

this array contain diferent objects of the tipe "Class" and some null spaces.
i need to check if there is on the same day(first "[]") 2 equal objects of the tipe "Class" and if they are i need to check if they are consecutive like one its in timetable[1][2]and the other its in timetable [1][3] or timetable[1][1] and if they are not i need to do this

```
fitnnes -= 100;
```

how can i do this?

Comment: Please format your question.  This makes no sense:  same day(first "[]") 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take your description of the problem, and translate it into Java, then it will become something like this:

```
int nextFitness(int fitness, Object[][] timetable) {
    for (Object[] day : timetable)                        // "on the same day"
        for (int hour = 0; hour < Main.hours - 1; hour++) // "consecutive"
            if (Objects.equals(day[hour], day[hour + 1])) // "equal"
                fitness -= 100;                           // "i need to do this"
    return fitness;
}
```